# How to edit multiple excel files each of which are in a different folder united in one folder

Tags: vba, excel, subdirectory

This question isn't supposed to be complicated. I have one big folder and in it it has 200 individual folders. Now each of those folders has one excel sheet in it. I want to have some code in a vba file in control folder (which is next to the 200) which can iterate over the 200 folders and change one bit of data in each excel file. I found directory stuff and folder iterations, However I can't take bit for here and there and merge them together, i need some simple help.

my code is currently: `Sub Button1_Click()

```
Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim ws      As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iIndex  As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String

'Get the directories
strPath = "C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\"
strFile = Dir(strPath, vbDirectory)

'Loop through the dirs
Do While strFile <> ""

    'Open the workbook.
    strFileName = Dir(strPath & strFile & "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm", vbDirectory)
    'Open the workbook.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile & "\" & strFileName, ReadOnly:=False)

    'Loop through the sheets.

    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(1)

    'Do whatever



    'Close the workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Move to the next dir.
    strFile = Dir
Loop
```

End Sub
`

Please help @MatthewD

Comment: it's pretty complicated if you don't show us the code you have written so far to get it working. Conceptually, it may be simple, which is it, but without code there's no way any of us could dream up the exact specific details you need to color the framework of your project. If you post the code you've tried we can help you edit. Not many are willing to do it for you.

Comment: well, i'm not exactly sure where to start. i know the code needs to first grab the main folder and then loop over each folder. then for each folder i know it needs to make a workbook and then call the first sheet and then make the necessary edits. its just a loop and some code but i don't know how to call the directory of the original folder and then loop all the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show code, it's something like this.

```
    Dim wb      As Workbook
    Dim ws      As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iIndex  As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    'Get the directories
    strPath = "c:\temp\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath, vbDirectory)

    'Loop through the dirs
    Do While strFile <> ""

        'Open the workbook. 
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strPath & strFile & "\filename.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

        'Loop through the sheets.
        For iIndex = 1 To Application.Worksheets.count
            Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

            'Do whatever

        Next iIndex

        'Close the workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        'Move to the next dir.
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
```

If the workbook names are not known, you'll have to dir the xlsx file in the dir.

```
    strFileName = Dir(strPath & strFile & "*.xlsx")
    'Open the workbook. 
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strPath & strFile & "\" & strFileName , ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: why save changes = false. if i want to save just change that to true?

Comment: also why `ReadOnly` if the user needs to change a file? And, how does the code loop the subfolders -> which is what the OP is asking?

Comment: and strPath is the main folder?

Comment: @Simcha Hoffmann That was just some code that I copied out of my workbook. Not sure what he really needs. Not sure if the looping sheets is needed either.

Comment: Yes, strPath is the dir that all the other dirs are in.

Comment: but also is there a specific location this should run in?

Comment: It does not "really" matter where it is run from.  I put a few comments in. You can figure out what it is going on by doing some debugging.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewD

Comment: @MatthewD i keep on getting the problem that they cant find the directory. I have the directory C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\New folder where "testing main folder" holds them all and "New Folder" is the first of the 200 folders. what am i doing wrong? (also i changed them to .xlsm files)

Comment: You should have `strPath = "C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\"`

Comment: i added to the question. please help @MatthewD

Comment: also it show the problem as "run time error '1004'   we could not find "C:\User\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should be pretty easy.  Simply list every file in all the folders, recursively.  The script below will do that for you.

```
Sub ListAllFiles()
    SearchForFiles "C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\YourFolder\", "writefilestosheet", "*.*", True, True
End Sub

Sub searchForFiles(ByVal DirToSearch As String, ByVal ProcToCall As String, _
        Optional ByVal FileTypeToFind As String = "*.*", _
        Optional ByVal SearchSubDir As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal FilesFirst As Boolean = False)
    On Error GoTo ErrXIT
    If Right(DirToSearch, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
        DirToSearch = DirToSearch & Application.PathSeparator

If FilesFirst Then processFiles DirToSearch, ProcToCall, FileTypeToFind
If SearchSubDir Then processSubFolders DirToSearch, ProcToCall, _
    FileTypeToFind, SearchSubDir, FilesFirst

    If Not FilesFirst Then _
        processFiles DirToSearch, ProcToCall, FileTypeToFind
    Exit Sub
ErrXIT:
    MsgBox "Fatal error: " & Err.Description & " (Code=" & Err.Number & ")"
    Exit Sub
End Sub


Private Sub processFiles(ByVal DirToSearch As String, _
            ByVal ProcToCall As String, _
            ByVal FileTypeToFind As String)
        Dim aFile As String
        aFile = Dir(DirToSearch & FileTypeToFind)
        Do While aFile <> ""
            Application.Run ProcToCall, DirToSearch & aFile
            aFile = Dir()
            Loop
End Sub


Sub writeFilesToSheet(ByVal aFilename As String)
    With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = aFilename
        End With
End Sub
```

Next, as you're aware of, you'll need to access each file, using the technique above, open each, make your change, save it, and close the file.  Use the technique described from the URL below, to make the changes.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win010.htm

You'll have to modify the script just a bit, because that looks for all files on one folder, you need Ron's script to run through the different paths you created with the first script